# BPMN: alternative to task to gateway link

Tags: bpmn, bpmn.io

I am learning BPMN.

I am trying to use https://demo.bpmn.io to create examples from mg documentation.

In particuar in the pizza example i am trying to model the flow that from the task "Ask for pizza" goes back to the event based gateway:
[image: exapmle from omg docs]

my tool does not allow to link a task with a gateway, but i sorted out this:
[image: alternative solution with bpmn.io]

is this an alternative witht the same meaning?

Thanks.

Comment: Could you explain in prose what you want to express with this diagram? Apart from the formal errors (both parallel gateways only have action that can happen instead of multiple, there is no description for your send event) I don't understand the meaning. The first diagram says "Wait for the pizza. After 60 minutes, ask for it. Then wait again".

Comment: I also don't understand which tool you are using that does not allow linking a task to a gateway. Are you not using bpmn.io as mentioned at the beginning of your post ?